# Entity Framework: One-To-Many?

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I'm juggling with One-To-Many relationship using Entity Framework:

I need to insert a bunch of data from C# objects into my SQL Server database, so I have been using Entity Framework with the Code First approach.

In my example, I have a product which have one category, yet categories can obviously belong to multiple products.

My Product-class looks like this.

```
    public class Product
    {
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried multiple solutions for my Category class, both with and without the outcommented line but here we go:

```
    public class Category
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
 // public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

When inserting multiple products, with the same category, I get a Primary key constraint violation - which I understand why happens, but I would think Entity Framework would care of!

I have a long list of indexes, that I use to get an XML-file (based on that index) from an API. I then create an object based on that XML file. The method is called GetProductFromXML:

```
Foreach(int index in listOfIndexes){
   Product product = GetProductFromXML(index);
   productContext.Products.Add(product);
 }
Context.SaveChanges();
```

When ever I get a product, where the category already exists, I get an violation of primary key constraint-exception from my Category-table.

What I want is obviously that EF understands, that the second object should use the category from the first object.

What do I do? I find this such a simple action, that would be easily done with normal querying, but with Entity Framework I wrap my head around it and I'm going nuts!

Hope someone will give me the logic answer!

Comment: It looks like GetProductFromXML is creating a new Category.  Entity framework has a flag to indicate if an entity is new or not.  If you create it and add it in as new, then you will get a primary key violation.

Comment: Great answer! This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating *two* new `Category` instances and explicitly giving them both the same `CategoryId`.  (You're also not actually *using* either instance for your products, and you never set any properties on the second product.  I'm assuming these are typos.)

Only create one instance:

```
Category category = new Category();
category.CategoryId = 1;
category.CategoryName = "categoryA";
```

Then use it for both of your `Product` instances:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.ProductId = 1;
product.Name = "ProductA";
product.Category = category;
context.Products.Add(product);

Product productB = new Product();
productB.ProductId = 2;
productB.Name = "ProductB";
productB.Category = category;
context.Products.Add(productB);
```

**Edit:** From a lengthy comment thread below (and the updated question which obscures the failing code behind a new method), the original problem still remains... You're creating new `Category` instances where you should be re-using existing instances.

Consider keeping them in a list outside of your method.  As a logical guide, something like this:

```
// Note: If there are categories from previous runs of this logic
//       then you should fetch them from the backing data here
var categories = new List<Category>();

foreach (int index in listOfIndexes)
{
    var product = GetProductFromXML(index, categories);
    productContext.Products.Add(product);
}
Context.SaveChanges();
```

And witin your `GetProductFromXML` method:

```
int id = // ... get the Product ID from your XML
string name = // ... get the Product Name from your XML
//... etc.
string categoryName = // ... get the Category Name from your XML

var category = categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);
if (category = null)
{
    // It doesn't exist yet, so add it
    category = new Category();
    category.Name = categoryName;
    category.CategoryId = // ... whatever logic you use to determine this
    categories.Add(category);
}

return new Product
{
    ProductId = id,
    Name = name,
    // etc.
    Category = category
};
```

Comment: I deem this answer incorrect. To clarify:
This example is obviously for simplification. I don't create the products like this. They are created dynamically (from an XML file) and there are approximately 1.000.000 products that need to be inserted. 
I tried to run your example. First run, with productA and productB, actually runs smooth and both products gets inserted with the same CategoryId as intended. But if i run the same bode again - this time with productC and productD I (exactly like in my originally post) get the exception:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Categories'.

Comment: With your code I would have to run all products in one code run. Which cannot possible be the point of Entity Framework

Comment: @denUdvalgte: Instead of describing the code you're using, can you update your question to demonstrate it?  You claim the code in this answer works for the first two products, but then something fails when you add more products.  So... how are you adding more?  What specifically are you doing?  Edit the question to demonstrate.

Comment: That is fair. I will do that

Comment: @denUdvalgte: You've drastically changed the question, and obscured the failing code behind whatever `GetProductFromXML` is.  It sounds like it's still the same problem though... Creating multiple instances with the same ID.  It sounds like whatever is happening within `GetProductFromXML` needs to be aware of the ongoing list of available categories.  For example, maintain a unique list of categories outside that method.  In the method, check if the one you want already exists before creating a new one.  The overall premise is still the same, don't duplicate your instances.

Comment: I guess, what I basically asks is, is it really true that Entity Framework can't dynamically checks whether and key isn't already in the table, and if it is use that key? Seems like such a simple and straight forward action?

Comment: @denUdvalgte: Under different circumstances EF can do a variety of things.  But that's not what *your code* is telling it to do.  Your code is explicitly telling it that the key is not auto-generated and that you will supply key values on each instance.  Then your code supplies duplicate key values, resulting in the error.  Alternatively, you can insert all of your categories before you insert any products, then just set the corresponding `CategoryId` value on each `Product` instance.  EF will know to associate it to the correct record from that.

Comment: I see your point. But if the key autogenerated, the category name gets added multiple times.

Comment: @denUdvalgte: If your code adds multiple categories by the same name, yes.  Again, you need to either use an *existing* category or create a new one.  If you explicitly create a new one then EF will follow as it's told, creating a new one.

Comment: And since each product is created from an XML derived from an API call, it is not possible to create all Categories first, although that was a good idea too.

Comment: It seems like you know what I'm trying to do. Can you guide me in a direction of how I solve the issue?

Comment: I'm just assuming that creating an objecting in C# code and a database entry isn't necessarily the same thing?

Comment: @denUdvalgte: The direction is the same no matter how you approach it... If you want to use an existing category, you have to use an existing category instead of creating a new one.  As suggested previously, try keeping a list of known categories outside the scope of that method which assigns the category to the product.  When you read from the XML, see if the category already exists in the list and use it.  If it doesn't, add a new one to the list and use it.

Comment: The approach you are suggesting (with a list in the program memory) will result in (as I described in my very first comment to your post) that if I run my program again in a month (assuming that new products will be available in the API) that the program will throw the same exception, if the category was already in the database from the previous batch. 
That again seems like a bad solution

Comment: @denUdvalgte: Then include logic in the program which will read the previous categories from the database into that in-memory list.  Once again, the underlying problem hasn't changed.  You either (1) use an existing Category or (2) create a new Category.  Everything comes down to that.  You can think of a hundred scenarios in which your code is creating new categories, but each one of those scenarios is still failing for exactly the same reason.  The solution isn't "bad", you just keep insisting on not fully applying it.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to grasp the idea. Thanks, sir!